# Best practices for direction control in 2d game on mobile

Tags: mobile, controls, html5

I've been working on a pacman clone in HTML5 for quite a while. (http://pacman.platzh1rsch.ch)

One important thing for me was always to keep it responsive, so it would be playable on all different handheld sizes.
The big problem wit that is: it is way to hard to play on a mobile device.

On a desktop or laptop you can control Pacman using your keyboard's arrow keys or W-A-S-D, which - in my opinion - is really easy.

For touchscreen devices I added some buttons into the game and also the support for swipe gestures. Anyway, turns out it's still way too difficult to play for most of the users.

Do you know any better options on how to solve this issue?

[image]

EDIT:
Just adjusted the game to detect swipe gestures on the whole screen and I think it is already a pretty nice improvement. Thanks for all the hints, and suggestions!

Comment: The 'official' pacman game uses swipe controls, which I think are quite nice. The biggest advantage is having the full screen as a target rather than individual buttons.

Comment: True, but you cover the game area with your fingers and currently I want players to be able to pause the game by touching the screen too. It's a bit tricky.

Comment: Given your game screen doesn't cover the entire device screen, I don't know that that would be an issue. You could then have a dedicated button for pause (or, just detect tap vs. swipe).

Comment: Just adjusted the game to detect swipe gestures on the whole screen and I think it is already a pretty nice improvement. Thanks for all the hints, and suggestions!

Answer (score 4):

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0c7iC.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

I prefer games using this layout, emulating a joystick so you can tap and drag. It also allows you to simulate acceleration.

Comment: I'm a native english speaker I'm just very tired, someone help this sound like human.

Comment: I thought about this too, but I see a lot of problems in the implementation (sensity etc. ) anyway I guess it's also worth considering. Will post my opinion after I've tested it.

Comment: Let me know what you think, I love the joystick-ish thing.

Comment: I think the joystick might be a good idea, specially because you only need one hand to play, the controls are natural.
Since this is for a pacman implementation, you wouldn't have to deal with acceleration and some more complex interactions.

Comment: I'm just trying to implement https://github.com/jeromeetienne/virtualjoystick.js#readme but I have some issues. Any other good javascript implementations of joysticks?

Comment: Sorry :/ I don't know of any good virtual joysticks in javascript. That being said I'm sure there's a large number of them.

Answer (score 3):

I don't like to play games on my smartphone since it's often hard to control a character/car or whatever. But the games I've played the most had controls splitted to the left and the right so it's easier to tap with thumbs.

[image: games controls iPhone]

Little Acorns is a great example :

[image: Little Acorns]

Comment: I really like that idea! Thx! Will also test this and in the end, post which solution I chose and worked best.

Comment: But note that a side scroller is a very different gaming experience than Pac-Man.

Answer (score 2):

Use a Gameboy like type of inputs - it worked for years - don't know why it shouldn't work on mobile (I suggest this also as a Gameboy emulator user on my mobile phone).

Move the directional key "down" lower so the user can press it more easily with his thumb. Also increase the input a bit so it's easier to see which key is being pressed (also not all screens have the same touch acuracy, so a bigger input is better).

Also consider screen rotation - on horizontal screen move directional keys to the right and action keys (if you have any) to the left.

[image: Gameboy interface]

Comment: One issue would be that a Gameboy had physical buttons so you could tell which one you're pressing just by the tactile feel of them. Replicating the positioning / size of them on a touchscreen means you lose that tactile feedback so you don't know what you're pressing (which is equally problematic as you can't even *see* what you're pressing because you're thumbs will be in the way!) - Note: I'm not saying this is a *bad* suggestion, just that it's not without its issues.

Comment: @JonW - I've been playing Pokemon Gold on my old Nokia X6 for years now (I just love getting back to that game) - using a gameboy emulator which has the keys aranged in this way and never had the problems with it - true it is that the command inputs are a bit bigger than the buttons on gameboy - should have mentioned that in the post. Edited now.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I remember thinking about implementing some kind of virtual joystick, like on the old arcade pacman machines and my buttons kinda come from the gameboy idea. But I really like your idea of putting the controls to the side in landscape and distributing them more equally. I will see how I can implement it and will then get some new user feedbacks to tell you if it helped :)

Comment: @platzhersh - gameboy advance is actually the horizontal layout. The color one is vertical.

Answer (score 2):

There's another option that nobody here has mentioned. I see it a lot in Nokia Snake-like games on mobile, where there is the same limited range of motions:

- Continue straight ahead (no action needed)
- From the perspective of the snake/Pac-Man, turn **left**, and
- From the perspective of the snake/Pac-Man, turn **right**.

That means you can cut down the number of controls down to two: swipe left/right and/or tap left/right buttons. (Picture a first-person Pac-Man game, going through a maze if you're having trouble getting what I mean.)

The problem with this is that, at first, it would be difficult for the user to determine whether to press left or right while looking at a top-down representation using first-person controls. If Pac-Man is heading up on the screen, the left/right matches up with reality, but if he is going down, left/right is reversed, and the other two directions can be even more confusing.

Comment: I tought of this as well. Then I realized that Pac-Man can turn on its tracks, so there is an option to turn back in addition to turning left or right.

Comment: Good point. I never thought of that.

Answer (score 1):

The joy stick would give it that nice old school arcade look, but maybe basing the game off of an Accelerometer could be an option as well. This would mean controlling the movements by tilting your mobile device. Here's an article from 2012

http://www.webdigi.co.uk/blog/2012/using-an-ios-device-to-control-a-game-on-your-browser/

There are limitations, but it could be something to look into.